# Force GCC to always load a const (i.e. read-only) even with optimizations enabled

Tags: c, optimization, constants

Let's say I have a const global variable that is, therefore, read-only and will be placed in the .rodata section. I'm compiling the code with -O3 optimizations. This will make the compiler (i.e., GCC) generate different code when reading the variable, depending on the value of the variable itself. For example, if the variable is defined as zero or a small enough value that fits the ISA instructions immediate field, it will use a single instruction. If it is large, it might use several instructions. I'd like for the generated code to be the same independently of the value. I tried declaring it as `volatile const`, and this seems to work as it always generates load instructions to read the value, but GCC seems to ignore the const field and place it in the .data section. Also, I tried declaring `__attribute__((section(".rodata")) volatile`. This resulted in the warning " Warning: setting incorrect section attributes for .rodata".

So that I don't fall into an "XY problem" issue, I'd also say my main goal is for this code to generate a final binary that is as much as possible the same (i.e., sections at the same addresses with the same sizes), independently of the value of these const variables, which comes from macros generated at compile time. Also, I'd like these const values to be in the read-only data section such they are marked as RO in the page tables and can't be corrupted at runtime.

Any suggestions on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Still sounds like an XY problem to me. *Why* do you have all those requirements?

Comment: Well, I don't really want to describe the whole project. But I can add that I automatically compile this code twice, extracting information from the object the first time, which can then result in some of those variables being modified. Then, I need to recompile it again while guaranteeing the overall code layout remains unaltered, so the layout information retrieved from the object file in the first phase still holds. Otherwise, I would need to repeat the process again without guarantees that it would stabilize.

Comment: *Objects declared with const-qualified types **may** be placed in read-only memory by the compiler* If you need an object in `.rodata` section you have to specify this explicitly.
What version of gcc do you use? GCC 13.2.1 for x86_64 places `const volatile int` variable to `.rodata` by default and doesn't produce warning for `const volatile __attribute__((section(".rodata))) int`.

Comment: You cannot control that, as the optimizer is free to implement const values using immediate addressing, this is using instructions like `mov #3, r0`, where 3 is the value assigned to the `const` in the declaration.  If you are tied to a compiler, then you can, but I should never depend on this kind of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have enabled link-time optimizations, the compiler usually can do these optimization *only if* you defined the variable in the same `.c` file (translation unit).

Therefore you could define the variables in a different translation unit, e.g. `const.c`:

```
const int x = 42;
```

then elsewhere use

```
extern const int x;
```

then, unless you use link-time optimizations, the compiler just has to issue proper reads in other translation units because it wouldn't know otherwise.

---

You can use the X-macros to do these in one place, so that you can use something like

```
DEFINE_CONST_VAR(int, x, 42);
```

in an `#include` just once for each variable.

Comment: Thanks! This actually works. I can't believe I didn't think of it before! I had these const declared as static in header files.

Comment: It might not work if variables are placed in separate sections and the linker will be allowed to discard unused ones (it actually will not work for sure in this case)

Comment: Event if that happens, in this case, it won't be a problem. All the variables in question are guaranteed to be used.

Comment: @josecm it is dirty workaround not the solution - and it will not work as you will not use it other translation units (as you did not have `extern` before)

Comment: @0___________, I'm not sure I get your point. I just tested it. Modulo some corner cases that might not be present right now, it works. As long as I don't use the consts in the same TU as they are defined, as Antti suggested below.